# Java List - excluding an attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a list of an objects like this

```
    public class A {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    String age;
    String departmentName;

    public A(String name, String lastName, String age, String departmentName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                ", departmentName='" + departmentName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

i did this

```
List<com.example.vbv.entities.A> a = new ArrayList<>();
        A a1 = new A("tarik","josef","30","IT");
        A a2 = new A("john","smith","29","MC");
        A a3 = new A("anna","jcc","31","ST");

        a.add(a1);
        a.add(a2);
        a.add(a3);

        a.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

the output :

```
A{name='tarik', lastName='josef', age='30', departmentName='IT'}
A{name='john', lastName='smith', age='29', departmentName='MC'}
A{name='anna', lastName='jcc', age='31', departmentName='ST'}
```

I want to get all the attributes of the class except the `departmentName` in the list without losing the data. The goal of removing "departementName" from the list is to create a JSON object from list directly, i don't want the "departementName" showing in my JSON.

What i want:

```
A{name='tarik', lastName='josef', age='30'}
A{name='john', lastName='smith', age='29'}
A{name='anna', lastName='jcc', age='31'}
```

is there a solution using `stream()` function ?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question clearer.

Comment: Do you means you want a `List<String>` where each element is the `attr4` value of the `A` elements? If so, then yes, you can do that with a stream. Use `map` to convert each `A` into its `attr4` value, then collect to a list.

Comment: It's unclear what the result should look like - should e.g. that be a stream of maps where each key-value is the name of the field and its value? But yes, this is possible e.g. via reflection. It'd be easier if `A` was a `Record`, but you can do it with any class by accessing all the fields/compoenents and filtering out the one named `attr4`. Try seeing what `A.class.getDeclaredFields()` returns.

Comment: Actually, I'm voting to reopen. Yes, the question is not entirely clear, but _the heart_ of the question - getting fields and fields values, excluding a specific one, is crystal clear.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you take a look?

Comment: This is better, but it's still unclear why you can't change your `toString()` or add new method `toPersonalDetailsOnlyString()`. Even without changing the class itself, you could call `getName()`, `getLastName()`, etc. from the outside, and construct your string there. Do you need this for a single class? If yes, just write specialized toString method.

Comment: The goal of removing "departementName" from tlist is to create a JSON object from list directly, i don't want the "departementName" showing in my JSON. hope that's clear.

Comment: how do you create a JSON object? There are several ways for that. If you use `JSONObject` which is a map actually, you can do that.

Comment: In other words, you should have showed us your code for encoding the object into JSON, and asked how to encode the object without a field. Asking what you actually want instead of how you think of solving the problem is a big difference. Right now we still cannot recommend the best solution because we do not know whoch JSON library you're using and in which way. We're getting there, though!

Comment: Can you modify the code of class `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're using for your JSON generation and how you're actually producing your output, but here are the most common ways to achieve generating JSON output from a class with some exclusions.

I'm using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) in my examples, but most JSON libraries have similar mechanisms.

#### 1. Write a dedicated Data Transfer Object (DTO)

Normally you would not want the objects to escape from the core of your application (often known as your domain objects). For that reason it is very common to write DTOs, objects specifically designed with no logic, only data, that are then sent out over the wire. The upside of this approach is that it detaches the API of the application (public-facing classes) from the insides of the application. If you ever need to hide some fields from the public API, like in your case right here, or add some fields that are not in the domain, the DTOs will do the job.

There are two way to do this, classic DTOs with some copying and mapping:

```java
public class ADto {
    private final String name;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String age;

    public ADto(A a) {
        this.name = a.getName();
        this.lastName = a.getLastName();
        this.age = a.getAge();
    }

    // getters
}
```

or a "view" (a.k.a. adapter) class:

```java
public class ADto {
    private final A a;

    public ADto(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return a.getName();
    }
    
    // other getters
}
```

#### 2. Change your class to ignore the field in JSON

All modern JSON libraries will have some mechanisms to ignore specific properties. If you can modify the class in question, this tends to be the easiest way:

```java
public class A {
    private final String name;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String age;
    @JsonIgnore
    private final String departmentName;

    // ...
}
```

or

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "departmentName" })
public class A {
    private final String name;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String age;
    private final String departmentName;

    // ...
}
```

#### 3. Use a property filter object

Jackson of course allows you to filter properties of objects you don't own and cannot change, e.g. by using filters.

```java
PropertyFilter departmentNameFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("departmentName");
FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
    .addFilter("departmentNameFilter", departmentNameFilter);

JsonMapper mapper = new JsonMapper();
mapper.writer(filterProvider).writeValue(out, a);
```

#### 4. Do it manually via reflection

You can of course read the properties and their values manually via reflection into any structure you want, e.g. a map, explicitly skipping the `departmentName` if needed. Since you specifically asked for a Stream solution, here's one:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    A a1 = new A("name1", "lastname1", "age1", "deparment1");
    A a2 = new A("name2", "lastname2", "age2", "deparment2");

    List<Field> fields = Stream.of(A.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(field -> !field.getName().equals("departmentName"))
        .toList();

    List<Map<String, Object>> valuesByFieldNames = Stream.of(a1, a2)
        .map(object -> toMapOfValuesByFieldName(object, fields))
        .toList();
    System.out.println(valuesByFieldNames);
    // Prints:
    // [
    //    {lastName=lastname1, name=name1, age=age1},
    //    {lastName=lastname2, name=name2, age=age2}
    // ]
}

private static Map<String, Object> toMapOfValuesByFieldName(A object, List<Field> fields) {
    return fields.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                Field::getName,
                field -> getFieldValue(object, field)
        ));
}

private static Object getFieldValue(A object, Field field) {
    try {
        return field.get(object);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i want, Thank you so much <3

Comment: Glad I could help! Which method did you go with in the end?

Comment: The last one (via reflection).